# Unable to find elements with multiple classes assigned

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

If I used this code:

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using= ".//*[@class='leaflet-control-pan leaflet-control']")
private WebElement movingPageButtonsLocator;
```

The element movingPageButtonsLocator is found, but if I use following code it doesn't:

```
@FindBy(how = How.CLASS_NAME, using= "leaflet-control-pan leaflet-control")
private WebElement movingPageButtonsLocator;
```

Aren't both the same ?

If not, how is `How.XPATH` different from `How.CLASS_NAME` in this case ?

Comment: they are not the same, one is `XPATH` and matches any `XPATH` query, the other is something else, no where in the documentation does it suggest that they are equal in any way.

Answer (score 1):

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using= ".//*[@class='leaflet-control-pan leaflet-control']")
private WebElement movingPageButtonsLocator;
```

Will match any `XPATH` query, which can be anything on the page. Where `className` is a single class on an element if you want to match multiple classes on an element you need to use `@FindBys`.

According to the JavaDoc, this is how it should be:

```
@FindBys({@FindBy(how = How.CLASS_NAME, using= "leaflet-control-pan"),
          @FindBy(how = How.CLASS_NAME, using= "leaflet-control") })
private WebElement movingPageButtonsLocator;
```

or more succinctly:

```
@FindBys({@FindBy(className = "leaflet-control-pan"),
          @FindBy(className = "leaflet-control") })
private WebElement movingPageButtonsLocator;
```

[`@FindBys`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBys.html) is a logical `AND` it will only find where **both** `class` are on an `element`. *I think it should have been called `@FindByAll` to be semantically correct*

> Used to mark a field on a Page Object to indicate that lookup should
>   use a series of @FindBy tags in a chain as described in ByChained

[`@FindAll`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindAll.html) is a logical `OR` it find where any of the specified criteria match an `element`. *I think it should have been called `@FindByAny` to be semantically correct*

> Used to mark a field on a Page Object to indicate that lookup should
>   use a series of @FindBy tags It will then search for all elements that
>   match any of the FindBy criteria. Note that elements are not
>   guaranteed to be in document order.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using CSS Selector

```
 @FindBy(how = How.CSS, using= ".leaflet-control-pan.leaflet-control")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you will look at carefully `how = How.CLASS_NAME` says **class name** and not **class names**. see singular vs plural.

So **How.CLASS_NAME** should be used only when a element could be identified by single class.

Following will work, not sure if it will give you an element you are interested in or not.

```
@FindBy(how = How.CLASS_NAME, using= "leaflet-control-pan")
private WebElement movingPageButtonsLocator;
```